# FILESTREAM_WORKITEM_QUEUE high waits

Tags: sql-server-2012, sp-blitz, sp-blitzfirst

I've been using sp_BlitzFirst and logging the results every 15 minutes for the past 5 days. Using the new Power BI report from FirstResponderKit.org, I'm seeing a VERY large range of FILESTREAM_WORKITEM_QUEUE waits. The range for this wait is anywhere from near 0, to 2942 minutes. Total for the past 5 days is 16,406 minutes. This includes the weekend, which the server only has light usage.

What causes this wait and should I be concerned that it sometimes get above 2000 minutes for a 15 minute period?

This is SQL Server 2012 Standard with a 10-core processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, almost universally, any wait that is a queue or timing wait (especially one with `QUEUE` in the name), can largely be ignored. While this one is not explicitly listed in Paul Randal's [list of waits to ignore](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/), it may be more that this wait is rare than because it shouldn't be ignored. Across all of the instances uploading SQL Sentry wait data to the cloud, this wait type [has yet to be encountered](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/filestream_workitem_queue/) (compare that to, say, [`LCK_M_SCH_M`](https://www.sqlskills.com/help/waits/lck_m_sch_m/), a much more frequently observed wait type - seen on close to 1% of instances).

With the combination of:

- there are no blog posts about this wait type (that I could find);
- this is the first time it has been mentioned on this site *or* on Stack Overflow; and,
- Microsoft [hasn't even bothered to say anything about it beyond "TBD"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-wait-stats-transact-sql)...

...leads me to believe this is an innocuous wait that you shouldn't be concerned about.

And this is one of the problems I have with using a waits methodology for finding "problems" - is there any actual performance-related *symptom* involved with these waits? You're *always* going to have a wait that is the highest; that doesn't mean it's a problem. Now, if you can associate this wait type with observable performance symptoms in something related (such as reading from or writing to a filestream container), there might be more to investigate.

*Also, are you sure you are accurately translating to **minutes**? There have only been 7,200 minutes in the past 5 days, so I'm not sure how this wait type could have registered more than double that. I already feel this wait type can't be anything more than a timer, which means it's simply accumulating benign wait time, and I can't imagine this also happens in parallel. So maybe the minutes you quote are actually seconds or some other unit.*

Comment: Thanks. I try to get ahead of things before someone complains of a slowdown, so that's why I'm researching this wait. I also could not find much documentation and so I turned to asking here.  Because this is a 10-core (20 hyper) machine, there have been 144,000 minutes in 5 days - at least how I understand how minutes are tracked.