# How do I troubleshoot FILESTREAM_WORKITEM_QUEUE waits in SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server-2014, performance, wait-types, performance-tuning

Env: SQL Server 2014 SP2 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

I am seeing our top wait as FILESTREAM_WORKITEM_QUEUE, with average waits near 1s and over 5000 waits during a 2-hour period of time.

I haven't been able to find out much on this wait type.  Some recommend to ignore it.  Any more info on this wait and how to address it (or not)?

TIA,
-Peter

Comment: As you stated, there really isn't a lot of info about this wait type. It is for "internal use" per the MS docs. See Aaron's response to a question about this from 2017: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192360/filestream-workitem-queue-high-waits

Comment: Saw that.  Thanks. Leaning towards ignoring this wait.